# Single or multiple connections to MongoDB is better?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, database-connection, database

I'm building my Node.js application by Express. I have two choices to write code in order to connect to my MongoDB.

- First is to open a connection each time a query is performed

https://codeshare.io/a3AQXg

- Second is to create one single connection when starting app

https://codeshare.io/GkmR14

Then

```
function productRepository(db) {
    this.db = db;
};

productRepository.prototype.insert = function(item) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.db.collection('product').insertOne(item, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
};

module.exports = productRepository;
```

And

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {

    var productRepository = require('../model/product');
    var productRepoInstance = new productRepository(db);

    app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
        productRepoInstance.insert({ createdAt: new Date() }).then(
            (result) => res.send({ result: 1 }),
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
                res.send({ result: 0 });
            });
    });
};
```

I wonder which is better, and why?

Comment: Put the the code in the question itself rather than linking to it.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Sorry, I tried to put it but the format does not apply all lines. I don't know know why

Comment: Bullets can't precede code blocks for some reason. So just remove those `- ` prefixes or see [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258120/cant-seem-to-get-a-code-block-to-be-formatted-correctly) about the problem for other options.